# Zen theme not showing second level menu items

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

I am creating a zen sub-theme and I edited the menu called "Main menu" to have on root level item that has 5 children (second level). The root level item shows up fine but none of the children are ever output in the HTML.

I verified they are all enabled. Just not sure why they aren't being sent back to the client. Does the Zen theme need some modification to support menus that are deeper than one level?

Comment: The parent item is set to `expanded` in the menu settings, right?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit your page.tpl.php**

Edit the section where the `primary_links` are printed to show the whole primary links menu instead of only showing the first level links of your primary links menu.

```
<?php if (isset($primary_links)) { ?>
     <div id="primary_menu">
<?php print theme('menu_tree',variable_get('menu_primary_menu',0)); ?>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**In Drupal 6**

```
<?php
$menu_name = variable_get('menu_primary_links_source', 'primary-links');
print menu_tree($menu_name);
?>
```

**Drupal 7**

```
<?php

    $menu_name = variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu');
    $tree = menu_tree($menu_name);
    print drupal_render($tree); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) or [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module to show 2nd level menu items.